# Find locations on a curve where the slope changes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have data points of time and voltage that create the curve shown below.

The `time` data is

```
array([  0.10810811,   0.75675676,   1.62162162,   2.59459459,
         3.56756757,   4.21621622,   4.97297297,   4.97297297,
         4.97297297,   4.97297297,   4.97297297,   4.97297297,
         4.97297297,   4.97297297,   5.08108108,   5.18918919,
         5.2972973 ,   5.51351351,   5.72972973,   5.94594595,
         6.27027027,   6.59459459,   7.13513514,   7.67567568,
         8.32432432,   9.18918919,  10.05405405,  10.91891892,
        11.78378378,  12.64864865,  13.51351351,  14.37837838,
        15.35135135,  16.32432432,  17.08108108,  18.16216216,
        19.02702703,  20.        ,  20.        ,  20.        ,
        20.        ,  20.        ,  20.        ,  20.        ,
        20.10810811,  20.21621622,  20.43243243,  20.64864865,
        20.97297297,  21.40540541,  22.05405405,  22.91891892,
        23.78378378,  24.86486486,  25.83783784,  26.7027027 ,
        27.56756757,  28.54054054,  29.51351351,  30.48648649,
        31.56756757,  32.64864865,  33.62162162,  34.59459459,
        35.67567568,  36.64864865,  37.62162162,  38.59459459,
        39.67567568,  40.75675676,  41.83783784,  42.81081081,
        43.89189189,  44.97297297,  46.05405405,  47.02702703,
        48.10810811,  49.18918919,  50.27027027,  51.35135135,
        52.43243243,  53.51351351,  54.48648649,  55.56756757,
        56.75675676,  57.72972973,  58.81081081,  59.89189189])
```

and the `volts` data is

```
array([ 4.11041056,  4.11041056,  4.11041056,  4.11041056,  4.11041056,
        4.11041056,  4.11041056,  4.10454545,  4.09794721,  4.09208211,
        4.08621701,  4.07961877,  4.07228739,  4.06568915,  4.05909091,
        4.05175953,  4.04516129,  4.03782991,  4.03123167,  4.02463343,
        4.01803519,  4.01217009,  4.00557185,  3.99970674,  3.99384164,
        3.98797654,  3.98284457,  3.97771261,  3.97331378,  3.96891496,
        3.96451613,  3.96085044,  3.95645161,  3.95205279,  3.9483871 ,
        3.94398827,  3.94032258,  3.93665689,  3.94325513,  3.94985337,
        3.95645161,  3.96378299,  3.97038123,  3.97624633,  3.98284457,
        3.98944282,  3.99604106,  4.0026393 ,  4.00923754,  4.01510264,
        4.02096774,  4.02609971,  4.02903226,  4.03196481,  4.03416422,
        4.0356305 ,  4.03709677,  4.03856305,  4.03929619,  4.04002933,
        4.04076246,  4.04222874,  4.04296188,  4.04296188,  4.04369501,
        4.04442815,  4.04516129,  4.04516129,  4.04589443,  4.04589443,
        4.04662757,  4.04662757,  4.0473607 ,  4.0473607 ,  4.04809384,
        4.04809384,  4.04809384,  4.04882698,  4.04882698,  4.04882698,
        4.04956012,  4.04956012,  4.04956012,  4.04956012,  4.05029326,
        4.05029326,  4.05029326,  4.05029326])
```

[image: plot of the curve]

I would like to determine the location of the points labeled A, B, C, D, and E. Point A is the first location where the slope goes from zero to undefined. Point B is the location where the line is no longer vertical. Point C is the minimum of the curve. Point D is where the curve is no longer vertical. Point E is where the slope is close to zero again. The Python code below determines the locations for points A and C.

```
tdiff = np.diff(time)
vdiff = np.diff(volts)

# point A
idxA = np.where(vdiff < 0)[0][0]
timeA = time[idxA]
voltA = volts[idxA]

# point C
idxC = volts.idxmin()
timeC = time[idxC]
voltC = volts[idxC]
```

[image: plot with points A and C]

How can I determine the other locations on the curve represented by points B, D, and E?

Comment: What determines those points ? You provide neither the data nor a clear definition of what you are trying to do. Using the word "inflection point" is not going to help anything if you don't clearly define what you actually want. Those points certainly don't *look* like mathematical inflection points.

Comment: When you come to pandas community don't forget to come with some data. Data determines the answer.

Comment: So what's special about those points? Please edit that into the question in an excruciating amount of detail. If you do it right, you'll probably be able to answer your own question .

Comment: what's wrong with just implementing the mathematical definition: where the second derivative changes sign?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I changed the title to better represent my question.

Comment: @Bharath I added the data for `time` and `volts`.

Comment: Much better. This is answerable. Do you understand what "slope" means in this context?

Comment: What does any of this have to do with pandas?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Slope as in the slope between a pair of data points. Pandas is used to read the data from a csv file and `idxmin()` is a pandas function.

Comment: I still am figuring out what no longer vertical mean here? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Bharath The are two vertical sections on the curve. The first is from point A to B and the second is from point C to D.

Comment: Why do you have multiple datapoints at the same point in time? That makes the function unable to be derived.

Comment: @Sebastian. OP is looking for the points where such regions start and end. The lack of derivative is not a concern in terms of finding a solution but I am curious as to what physical phenomenon OP is modeling or measuring that has multiple values at one time.

Comment: @Bharath. Vertical literally means sharing the same time value.

Comment: @Bharath. Vertical literally means sharing the same time value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the points that mark any location where the slope changes to or from zero or infinity. We do not not actually need to compute slopes anywhere: either `yn - yn-1 == 0` and `yn+1 - yn != 0`, or vice versa, or the same for `x`.

We can take the diff of `x`. If one of two successive elements is zero, then the diff of the diff will be the diff or the negative diff at that point. So we just want to find and label all points where `diff(x) == diff(diff(x))` and `diff(x) != 0`, properly adjusted for differences in size between the arrays of course. We also want all the points where the same is true for `y`.

In numpy terms, this is can be written as follows

```
def masks(vec):
    d = np.diff(vec)
    dd = np.diff(d)

    # Mask of locations where graph goes to vertical or horizontal, depending on vec
    to_mask = ((d[:-1] != 0) & (d[:-1] == -dd))
    # Mask of locations where graph comes from vertical or horizontal, depending on vec
    from_mask = ((d[1:] != 0) & (d[1:] == dd))
    return to_mask, from_mask

to_vert_mask, from_vert_mask = masks(time)
to_horiz_mask, from_horiz_mask = masks(volts)
```

Keep in mind that the masks are computed on second order differences, so they are two elements shorter than the inputs. Elements in the masks correspond to elements in the input arrays with a one-element border on the leading and trailing edge (hence the index `[1:-1]` below). You can convert the mask to indices using [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) or you can get the x- and y-values directly using the masks as indices:

```
def apply_mask(mask, x, y):
    return x[1:-1][mask], y[1:-1][mask]

to_vert_t, to_vert_v = apply_mask(to_vert_mask, time, volts)
from_vert_t, from_vert_v = apply_mask(from_vert_mask, time, volts)
to_horiz_t, to_horiz_v = apply_mask(to_horiz_mask, time, volts)
from_horiz_t, from_horiz_v = apply_mask(from_horiz_mask, time, volts)

plt.plot(time, volts, 'b-')
plt.plot(to_vert_t, to_vert_v, 'r^', label='Plot goes vertical')
plt.plot(from_vert_t, from_vert_v, 'kv', label='Plot stops being vertical')
plt.plot(to_horiz_t, to_horiz_v, 'r>', label='Plot goes horizontal')
plt.plot(from_horiz_t, from_horiz_v, 'k<', label='Plot stops being horizontal')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

Notice that because the classification is done separately, "Point A" is correctly identified as being both a spot where verticalness starts and horizontalness ends. The problem is that "Point E" does not appear to be resolvable as such according to these criteria. Zooming in shows that all of the proliferated points correctly identify horizontal line segments:

[image]

You could choose a "correct" version of "Point E" by discarding `from_horiz` completely, and only the last value from `to_horiz`:

```
to_horiz_t, to_horiz_v = apply_mask(to_horiz_mask, time, volts)
to_horiz_t, to_horiz_v = to_horiz_t[-1], to_horiz_v[-1]

plt.plot(time, volts, 'b-')
plt.plot(*apply_mask(to_vert_mask, time, volts), 'r^', label='Plot goes vertical')
plt.plot(*apply_mask(from_vert_mask, time, volts), 'kv', label='Plot stops being vertical')
plt.plot(to_horiz_t, to_horiz_v, 'r>', label='Plot goes horizontal')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I am using this as a showcase for the star expansion of the results of `apply_mask`. The resulting plot is:

[image]

This is pretty much exactly the plot you were looking for. Discarding `from_horiz` also makes "Point A" be identified only as a drop to vertical, which is nice.

As multiple values in `to_horiz` show, this method is very sensitive to noise within the data. Your data is quite smooth, but this approach is unlikely to ever work with raw unfiltered measurements.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer.

Comment: @wigging. Glad you liked it. I updated the pictures to look a bit cleaner.